useEffectを実行させたくない
機能概要
以下の機能をReactで作成しています。

詳細モーダルを開いた際にバックエンドからの取得データを表示したい
詳細モーダルでは「粗利」という項目があり「売り上げ」と「コスト」を入力すると自動計算されるようにしたい

困ってること
上記で、自動計算の値と違う粗利を保存したい際に、手入力でDBに保存しますが、詳細モーダルを開くとDBに保存した粗利ではなく自動計算された粗利が表示されてしましいます。
そのため、詳細モーダルを開いたときには自動計算されないようにし、入力内容が変更されたら自動計算をONにしたいです。
現在の状況

モーダル開く
useEffectによりfetch部分が動作し、profit, revenue, costの値が初期値の0から変更
useEffectの自動計算が作動し、DBの値では無く自動計算結果が表示される

コード
const [profit, setProfit] = useState<number>(0);
const [revenue, setRevenue] = useState<number>(0);
const [cost, setCost] = useState<number>(0);
const [modal, setModal] = useState<boolean>(false);

// モーダル開いた際にデータ取得し、粗利を更新
useEffect(() => {(
  fetch("endPoint")
   .then((res) => res.json())
   .then((json) => setProfit(json.data.profit))
),[
  modal
]}

// 粗利の自動計算
useEffect(() => {(
  setProfit(revenue - cost);
),[
  revenue, cost 
]}




初回レンダリング時に、二つの目の useEffect が呼ばれなければ解決するのでしょうか？そうであれば、こちら「https://zenn.dev/akky1991/articles/0612acf04bc044」は、参考にならないでしょうか？

一言で表すと、このような仕様の場合には 「エフェクトではなくイベントハンドラの中で計算する」 のが最良だと思います。

準備として、revenue, cost から revenue を計算する関数を、コンポーネントの外側においておきます。（コンポーネントの状態によらず、入力から出力が決まるように抜き出したので）
const calcProfit = ({ revenue, cost }: { revenue: number; cost: number }) =>
  revenue - cost;

そして、calcProfit は、useEffect の中ではなく、revenue, cost それぞれの input を更新するイベントハンドラの中で計算するべきです。
提示された仕様が、「いつ profit を計算して、いつ計算しないか」という分岐があって、複雑だからです。このような場合には useEffect は不適です。
参考までに、React 公式ドキュメントの該当記事の URL を共有しておきます。React は「こう動くだろう」という直感のイメージと異なる挙動をとるので、しっかりと目を通すことをオススメしいます。

そのエフェクトは不要かも ― React #計算の数珠繋ぎ

https://ja.react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#chains-of-computations



  const handleChangeRevenue: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    const revenue = Number.parseInt(e.target.value);
    const profit = calcProfit({ revenue, cost });
    setRevenue(revenue);
    setProfit(profit);
  };

  const handleChangeCost: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    const cost = Number.parseInt(e.target.value);
    const profit = calcProfit({ cost, revenue });
    setCost(cost);
    setProfit(profit);
  };

  const handleChangeProfit: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    const profit = Number.parseInt(e.target.value);
    setProfit(profit);
  };

  // 中略
    <input
      value={revenue}
      onChange={handleChangeRevenue}
    />
  


ついでに、下のように書くと正しく動きません。（すでにこのようなコードを書いて躓いたことがあるかもしれません。）が、その理由についても、上記のリンク先（「計算の数珠繋ぎ」の節の末尾）に書かれています。
  const handleChangeRevenue: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    setRevenue(Number.parseInt(e.target.value));
    setProfit(calcProfit({ revenue, cost }));
  };

